# Python version of AddFontResource()

Tags: python, windows, powershell, fonts

I'm currently trying to install fonts across a bunch of servers. I've been able to use a script to copy the fonts over and "install" them onto the server but I need to be able to access the fonts **without** having to turn off the server or log off the account.

I found Windows `AddFontResource()` which is done using C++, but is there an equivalent function in Python or Powershell?

(I've been using Python and Powershell to do checks and installations.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the `win32api` library? It has the `SendMessage()` function which can be used in conjunction with the `windll.gdi32.AddFontResource()` in `ctypes`

For example installing a TTF font file:

```
import win32api
import ctypes
import win32con


ctypes.windll.gdi32.AddFontResourceA("C:\\Path\\To\\Font\\font.ttf")
win32api.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_FONTCHANGE)
```

Comment: Please avoid the legacy [A]NSI API. You're unnecessarily limiting the path, which should be able to contain any Unicode characters, plus the code as written won't work in Python 3. Use `gdi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('gdi32');` `gdi32.AddFontResourceW.argtypes = (ctypes.c_wchar_p,);` `gdi32.AddFontResourceW(r"C:\Path\To\Font\font.ttf")`. I defined `argtypes` to allow ctypes in Python 2 to automatically convert a byte-string path using the `'mbcs'` codec. For the full character range use a `u""` literal.